# Why does the program keeps giving me segmentation fault when I'm trying to make a user defined queue?

Tags: c, queue

Please help me find the mistake.

I was trying to make a circular queue in which the size of the queue as well as the elements inside of the queue are user defined. The code works fine when I am not using loop but as soon as I use the loop it starts showing segmentation fault.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1xg3.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node node;

typedef struct{
    node *head;
    node *tail;
} queue;

void createqueue(queue *q){
    q->head = NULL;
    q->tail = NULL;
    return;
}
int enqueue(queue *q, int value){
    node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (newnode==NULL) return 0;
    newnode->data = value;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if(q->tail!=NULL){
        q->tail->next = newnode;
    }
    q->tail = newnode;
    q->tail->next = q->head;
    if(q->head == NULL){
        q->head=newnode;
    }
    return 1;
}

int dequeue(queue *q){
    if (q->head==NULL) return 0;
    q->head = q->head->next;
    q->tail->next = q->head;
    return 1;
}

int display(queue *q){
    node *printval;
    printval = q->head;
    if(printval==NULL) return 0;
    printf("\n");
    do
    {
        printf("%d-->",printval->data);
        printval = printval->next;
    } while (printval!=q->head);
    
}

int main(){
    queue *root;
    createqueue(root);
    printf("Enter the size of the queue");
    int size;
    scanf("%d",&size);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        int value;
        printf("Enter the value of the %d element",i);
        scanf("%d",&value);
        enqueue(root,value);
    }
    display(root);

}
```

Comment: It's not enough to declare a `root` pointer, you need to actually allocate memory under it.

Comment: `queue *root;` leaves `root` uninitialized. When you pass it to `createqueue` and attempt to derefernce it, you get [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). I don't know which compiler you are using, but MSVC warns about it.

Comment: @Harshit Singh, Consider `queue *root;  createqueue(root);` --> `queue root; createqueue(&root);`, `enqueue(root,value);` --> `enqueue(&root,value);`, ....  Tip: Be sure to compile with all warnings enabled.

Comment: Running under Valgrind is usually the first stop for pointer corruption issues - what output did that give?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Can you plz explain why its working now? when i am not using loop the root is initialized properly but in this step i have to replace the root with its address and it works fine. This is my first time having this problem even while creating a user defined linkedlist  never encountered this sort of problem.

Comment: @HarshitSingh [@Toby Speight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76641967/2410359) offer a good explanation.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica  how can i enable all warnings on gcc ?

Comment: @HarshitSingh "enable all warnings on gcc" --> Try first what [@Toby Speight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76641967/2410359) did: `Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Wconversion  -Wstrict-prototypes`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica and how do i do that ?   I am beginner currently using code runner to run my codes in visual studio code i dont know much about compilers. should i add the the warnings in task.json or there is some other way

Comment: @HarshitSingh I am unfamiliar with _code runner_ and _task.json_.  Consider seeking someone who knows those well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a function `createqueue` you use a pointer to an object for which memory was not allocated. You need to call malloc first and then set head and tail to a null.

```
queue* createQueue()
{
    queue* q = malloc(sizeof(queue));
    if (q != NULL) {
        q->head = NULL;
        q->tail = NULL;
    }
    return q;
}

// ...

int main()
{
    queue* q = createQueue();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Don't dereference the result of `malloc()` until you know it's not a null pointer.  That's a terrible example to show a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler warnings should have identified that you used `root` without ever pointing it to a valid `queue` object:

```
gcc-11 -std=c17 -fPIC -gdwarf-4 -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Wconversion  -Wstrict-prototypes -fanalyzer       76641886.c    -o 76641886
76641886.c:56:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
   56 | int main(){
      |     ^~~~
76641886.c: In function ‘display’:
76641886.c:54:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   54 | }
      | ^
76641886.c: In function ‘main’:
76641886.c:58:5: warning: ‘root’ is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]
   58 |     createqueue(root);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

See that **`root` is used uninitialized**?  That's your problem.

You need something like

```
    queue my_queue = { NULL, NULL };
    queue *const root = &my_queue;
    createqueue(root);
```

You'll still have issues to fix after that change:

```
76641886.c:50:9: warning: dereference of NULL ‘printval’ [CWE-476] [-Wanalyzer-null-dereference]
   50 |         printf("%d-->",printval->data);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ‘main’: events 1-6
    |
    |   56 | int main(){
    |      |     ^~~~
    |      |     |
    |      |     (1) entry to ‘main’
    |   57 |     queue my_queue = { NULL, NULL };
    |      |           ~~~~~~~~
    |      |           |
    |      |           (2) ‘my_queue.head’ is NULL
    |      |           (3) ‘my_queue.tail’ is NULL
    |......
    |   63 |     for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    |      |                 ~~~~~~
    |      |                  |
    |      |                  (4) following ‘true’ branch...
    |   64 |         int value;
    |   65 |         printf("Enter the value of the %d element",i);
    |      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    |      |         |
    |      |         (5) ...to here
    |   66 |         scanf("%d",&value);
    |   67 |         enqueue(root,value);
    |      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    |      |         |
    |      |         (6) calling ‘enqueue’ from ‘main’
    |
    +--> ‘enqueue’: events 7-16
           |
           |   20 | int enqueue(queue *q, int value){
           |      |     ^~~~~~~
           |      |     |
           |      |     (7) entry to ‘enqueue’
           |   21 |     node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
           |   22 |     if (newnode==NULL) return 0;
           |      |        ~
           |      |        |
           |      |        (8) following ‘false’ branch (when ‘newnode’ is non-NULL)...
           |   23 |     newnode->data = value;
           |      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           |      |                   |
           |      |                   (9) ...to here
           |   24 |     newnode->next = NULL;
           |   25 |     if(q->tail!=NULL){
           |      |       ~~~~~~~~
           |      |       | |
           |      |       | (10) ‘my_queue.tail’ is NULL
           |      |       (11) following ‘false’ branch...
           |......
           |   28 |     q->tail = newnode;
           |      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           |      |             |
           |      |             (12) ...to here
           |   29 |     q->tail->next = q->head;
           |      |                     ~~~~~~~
           |      |                      |
           |      |                      (13) ‘my_queue.head’ is NULL
           |   30 |     if(q->head == NULL){
           |      |       ~~~~~~~~
           |      |       | |
           |      |       | (14) ‘my_queue.head’ is NULL
           |      |       (15) following ‘true’ branch...
           |   31 |         q->head=newnode;
           |      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           |      |                |
           |      |                (16) ...to here
           |
    <------+
    |
  ‘main’: events 17-18
    |
    |   67 |         enqueue(root,value);
    |      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    |      |         |
    |      |         (17) returning to ‘main’ from ‘enqueue’
    |   68 |     }
    |   69 |     display(root);
    |      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    |      |     |
    |      |     (18) calling ‘display’ from ‘main’
    |
    +--> ‘display’: events 19-25
           |
           |   43 | int display(queue *q){
           |      |     ^~~~~~~
           |      |     |
           |      |     (19) entry to ‘display’
           |......
           |   46 |     if(printval==NULL) return 0;
           |      |       ~
           |      |       |
           |      |       (20) following ‘false’ branch (when ‘printval’ is non-NULL)...
           |   47 |     printf("\n");
           |      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
           |      |     |
           |      |     (21) ...to here
           |......
           |   50 |         printf("%d-->",printval->data);
           |      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           |      |         |
           |      |         (24) ...to here
           |      |         (25) dereference of NULL ‘printval’
           |   51 |         printval = printval->next;
           |      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           |      |                  |
           |      |                  (22) ‘printval’ is NULL
           |   52 |     } while (printval!=q->head);
           |      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           |      |                      |
           |      |                      (23) following ‘true’ branch...
           |
```

Also, don't ever ignore the return value from `scanf()` - that leads to undefined behaviour in this program.

Comment: toby i dont get this kind of warning logs. Is there any way i can enable it?

Comment: Consult your compiler's manual.  If it doesn't have a suitable set of warning options, switch to a better compiler.

Comment: Which compiler do you use? I use gcc.

Comment: You can see which compiler I used simply by reading the command that's at the beginning of the first code-block.

Comment: I see you use gcc too. But for this kinda problems which set of warnings should i add?